# Multiple Definition of textFileRead(char*)

Tags: c++, definition

I'm using this header file to read textfiles ( I use it to load shader files) and I use it in two different classes.

I'm getting the error Multiple Definition of textFileRead(char*).

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef READFILE_H
#define READFILE_H

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "string"
#include "fstream"

char *textFileRead(char *fn) {

FILE *fp;
char *content = NULL;

int count=0;

if (fn != NULL) {
    fp = fopen(fn,"rt");

    if (fp != NULL) {

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  count = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);

        if (count > 0) {
            content = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count+1));
            count = fread(content,sizeof(char),count,fp);
            content[count] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
return content;
}


#endif READFILE_H
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions defined in the header need to be marked as `inline` to prevent multiple definition.

Either this, or separate the implementation to an implementation file.

Include guards guard against multiple definition in the same translation unit, this is a linker problem. The symbol is defined multiple times across translation units.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the code from your header file is included once only for each compilation unit. To do this, you put this at the beginning of the file:

```
#ifndef READFILE_H
#define READFILE_H
```

and this at the end:

```
#endif
```

Of course, the identifier READFILE_H should be unique for each file. Next thing to do is: leave  only declarations of your functions and classes in your header, implementations should live in a separate implementation file (.c or .cpp or .cc). So in your header you will have declaration of your function only:

```
char *textFileRead(char *);
```

and the definition of your function will be in a separate .c file.

Comment: OK, so you have the guards. Leave the declaration of your function in the header and move its definition to a separate .c file.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the function in the header file, which means that the compiler will make a copy of the same function in each source file where you include this header. When it comes to linking the object files the linker will not know which version to use. (It can not know they are the same, just that their signatures are the same.)

One way to fix this is to move the implementation to a source file, and leave the declaration in the header file, like this:

**readfile.h**

```
#ifndef READFILE_H
#define READFILE_H

char *textFileRead(char *fn);

#endif
```

**readfile.cpp**

```
#include "readfile.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

char *textFileRead(char *fn) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *content = NULL;
    int count=0;

    /* ... code ... */

    return content;
}
```

Another solution is to mark the function `inline` and leave the implementation in the header file. Like this:

```
#ifndef READFILE_H
#define READFILE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

inline char *textFileRead(char *fn) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *content = NULL;

    /* ... code ... */

    return content;
}
```

In this last case, the compiler *may* choose to inline the function where it is called rather than generating a call to it.

It is also possible to use `static` in place of `inline` in the above example, or to surround the definition in an anonymous namespace. However neither of these methods are recommended. Unless you have specific reasons you want to potentially inline your function and make its body available in the header file, I'd go for the first alternative.

Comment: gentlemen thank you very much. I've never come an error such as this before and it may sounded like a stupid question. None the less much oblige.

Comment: did I down vote? oh crap I wanted to press the tick button! oh sorry , and I dont have the necessary reputation to change it back. So sorry!

Comment: Either give an upvote if you think the answer is valuable. If you did vote down, the down arrow next to the score will be colored. Just click it again to undo. Of course if you think it was a bad answer a downvote is allright. A comment so I know why would be helpful, though.

Comment: oh erm I didn't vote you down in the end. I cant vote up or down because I luck the necessary reputation. I don't know who voted you down but I found yours and all the peoples answer here helpful. You just provided something I was missing and that was the "*" in the function declaration.

Comment: Read all answers. Functions can be defined in a header file just fine, which renders the logic behind your answer wrong.

Comment: The " which means that the compiler will make a copy of the same function in each source file where you include this header." to be exact. This would actually happen if you mark the function `static`, in which case it can still be defined in the header just fine (try it out).

Comment: Was trying to aswer the original posters question, not write a tutorial in C, but I'll update my answer anyways...

Comment: The correct solution is marking it inline. Static, for a function this big, will severely increase code size. No one is asking you for a tutorial in c, but at least don t give out false info.

Comment: I disagree with you there. Inlining a big function is not the way to go. Neither will it decrease code size compared to using just static, quite the contrary. However the question was about why he got linker errors, not about best practices for defining functions in header files. Inline or no inline, static (or anon namespace) is needed anyways to avoid linker errors.

Comment: **NO!** `static` is **not** needed. And shouldn't be used unless really needed. It seems like you don't know the difference between `static` or `inline` or what they do. You have two options - either take the constructive criticism and learn something from my comments, or don't, and keep arguing that you're right (you're not). Your choice. I won't argue about this anymore (not productive for me)

Comment: Also, note that `inline` doesn't inline the function - it's just a hint to the compiler in that sense. The compiler is free to choose - and it probably won't inline it since it's big. Read up on what `inline` actually does.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, of course I'm open to constructive critisism, and in this case I stand corrected. Hope you're more happy with the answer now. I'm aware that `inline` is a hint, but wasn't aware it changed linkage too. In C the `static` keyword is needed for this case. My mistake.

Comment: That's great! Sorry if that might have bin too harsh.